# Zend Paginator+Table Gateway: error

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2, zend-paginator, tablegateway

Error: elements of paginator are objects (not arrays). `var_dump($records)`:

```
object(Records\Model\Records)#240 (11) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(9) "5453gdfgd" ["email"]=> string(16) "igor@bk.ru" ["homepage"]=> string(0) "" ["text"]=> string(5) "ghjkj" ["image"]=> string(5) "Array" ["file"]=> string(0) "" ["ip"]=> NULL ["browser"]=> NULL ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-03-05 23:24:49" ["inputFilter":protected]=> NULL }  
object(Records\Model\Records)#241 (11) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(9) "5453gdfgd" ["email"]=> string(16) "igor@bk.ru" ["homepage"]=> string(0) "" ["text"]=> string(5) "ghjkj" ["image"]=> string(5) "Array" ["file"]=> string(0) "" ["ip"]=> NULL ["browser"]=> NULL ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-03-05 23:23:37" ["inputFilter":protected]=> NULL }
```

Controller:

```
    protected $recordsTable;
        public function indexAction()
        {
            $field = (string) $this->params()->fromRoute('field', 'date');
            $order = (string) $this->params()->fromRoute('order', 'desc');
            $array = $this->getRecordsTable()->fetchAll($field, $order);

            $paginator = new Paginator\Paginator(new Paginator\Adapter\Iterator($array));
            $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->params()->fromRoute('page', 1));
            $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(2);
            //print_r($paginator);
            $vm = new ViewModel(array('records' => $paginator));
            return $vm;
        }

    public function getRecordsTable()
        {
            if (!$this->recordsTable) {
                $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
                $this->recordsTable = $sm->get('Records\Model\RecordsTable');
            }
            return $this->recordsTable;
        }
```

RecordsTable:

```
    protected $tableGateway;

        public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
        {
            $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
        }

        public function fetchAll($field, $order)
        {
            $this->field = $field;
            $this->order = $order;
            $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
            $select->columns(array('date', 'name', 'email', 'homepage', 'text', 'image', 'file'));
            $select->order($this->field.' '.$this->order);        
            });
            $resultSet->buffer();
            $resultSet->next();

            return $resultSet;
        }
```

In View:

```
 foreach($records as $record) : ?>
     <?php var_dump($record); ?> <br />
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make `$records` as an array?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either return an array from the result set using its `toArray` method...

```
public function fetchAll($field, $order)
{
     // ...
     return $resultSet->toArray();
}
```

Or in your view, use the `toArray` method in your foreach

```
<?php foreach($records->toArray() as $record) : ?>
    <?php var_dump($record); ?> <br />
<?php endforeach;
```

Comment: Additional information:
Zend\Db\ResultSet\Exception\RuntimeException

File:

    /opt/lampp/htdocs/guest-book/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/ResultSet/AbstractResultSet.php:265

Message:

    Rows as part of this DataSource, with type object cannot be cast to an array

Comment: Ah. Does your model have a 'getArrayCopy()` method?     `public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }`

Comment: K, how about a `toArray()` method (same functionality)? Think the getArrayCopy method only gets used if the model is an ArrayObject instance (at least as far as results sets go).

Comment: Thanks for help. What am I have to do? As we see, model is an ArrayObject instanceю

Comment: Did you implement the toArray() method as suggested? The error you see comes from the resultsets toArray method trying to call the toArray or getArrayCopy methods of your model object, and failing, so if you've implemented both, it should be working with at least one of them.

Comment: I understood, thanks! I've change my template and with toArray() it works.